# design pattern / multiple inheritance workaround java

Tags: java, design-patterns, multiple-inheritance

I have a Java package with a class hierarchy, say class A with subclasses A1, A2, A3, ...

For a specific application I need to make classes (of type A) which implement an interface B. These new classes will have some things in common so my first thought was to make a base class C which inherits from A and implements B, and my new classes C1, C2, C3, ... would just inherit from C.  However, some of these classes Ci will need functionality existing in one of the Aj and by this method I'd need to re-implement such functionality (functionality not defined in A).  For some of the Ci's I'd like to inherit behavior from the various Ai's, but at the same time inherit other behavior common to all Ci's which is in C.  Of course, Java won't allow multiple inheritance so I can't do this directly.  I certainly don't want to re-implement this much stuff just because MI is not supported, but I don't see a way around it.  Any ideas?

Comment: It might be easier if we had a diagram to see exactly what's going on.

Comment: It seems like in 80% times, the solution for multiple inheritance is `Strategy Pattern`. I never find the other 20% yet though.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need to subclass or do you just want code re-use?

Sounds like you use the  Composite and possibly Strategy Patterns:

Your Class C will have fields of type A and possibly B and delegate calls to them where appropriate.  This gives you all the advantages of code re-use without the messiness of inheritance (single or multi)

Comment: I was hoping for both subclasses and code re-use but yes the subclass relationship I need for this application is really only C with subclasses Ci (for polymorphism), but I don't think I need to subclass A and yeah maybe I can include a field of type A  in C and the various Ci can instantiate an object of type Aj as needed.  Seems good, I'm going think this through some more and try it if I don't foresee problems.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Everyone seems to notice this problem when they first begin seeing the usefulness of class hierarchies. The problem stems from orthogonal concerns in the classes. Some of the subclasses share characteristic 1 and some share characteristic 2. Some have neither. Some have both.

If there was just one characteristic ... (Say, some had an inside and so they could be filled.) ... we would be fine. Make an intermediate subclass to handle those concerns. Some subclasses actually subclass the intermediate one. And we are done.

But there are two and there is no way to do the subclassing. I suppose multiple inheritance is a solution to that problem but it adds a level of complexity and subverts the simplicity of thinking that makes hierarchical class structures useful.

I find it best to use subclassing for the one concern that it solves easily. Then pick a way to isolate and share the code besides subclassing.

One solution is to extract the functionality and move it elsewhere. Then all the Aj's and Ci's can call it there. The advantage is that you don't copy and paste any code and it can be fixed in one place if it gets broken.

**One** The code could go into the base class A and be given a name indicating it only applies to some of the children. Make the methods protected. Then call them from the actual classes. Its ugly but effective.

A

```
protected String formStringForSubclassesAjAndCi(String a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

Ci and Aj

```
public String formString(String a, int b) {
    return formStringForSubclassesAjAndCi(a, b);
}
```

**Two** Similarly you can put the shared code in some sort of helper class:

CiAjHelper

```
public static String formStringForSubclassesAjAndCi(String a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

Aj and Ci

```
public String formString(String a, int b) {
    return CaAjHelper.formStringForSubclassesAjAndCi(a, b);
}
```

**Three** The third way is to put the code in say, Aj, and then call it from the Cj by having an instance of the Aj for each Ci instance and delegating the common functions to it. (Its still ugly.)

Aj

```
public String formString(String a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

Cj

```
private Aj instanceAj = new Aj();

public String formString(String a, int b) {
    return instanceAj.formString(a, b);
}
```

Comment: true, but in this particular case i'd prefer to avoid changing the existing package if possible, i.e. the A and Ai's should hopefully stay fixed.  maybe that will be too much trouble and I'll come back to this.

Comment: Then #3 might help. Once I edit it to actually count from 1 to 3.